# jQuery AJAX call to .NET code-behind won't return

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

adAsText(file);

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/OnSubmit",
        rn "abcd";
}
```

it is a success and all the contents of the file prints as an alert, but I can't get it to return. It there something wrong with the content/data type?

Comment: what are you seeing for msg.d in _console.log(msg.d);_

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is not clear.
I think you should clear it as much as possible. The Error I see is that you are not calling the server side function anywhere. Then how you hope to be having returned data. First Call the function by passing a string value to it.

I think this is your problem, if not, please clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dataType to json. Even though it should infer, it's better to be explicit.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "WebForm1.aspx/OnSubmit",
    type: "POST",
    data: file,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "plain/text; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg.d);
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg.d);
        alert(file);
    }
});
```